# C# Interface Return Types

Tags: c#, interface

I have a couple of interfaces, IOrganisations and IPeople.

If I want to return a list of people associated with an organisation, which interface do I create this in?

The results are based on an *organisation*, yet I'm returning a list of *people*

Comment: The question is pretty vague, but from what i understand is: How about a Dictionary? like Dictionary<IOrganisation, List<IPeople>>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it on `IOrganisation`(and have `IPeople` as the return type).

Something like this:

```
interface IOrganisation {
    IList<IPeople> GetPeople();
}
```

This is because the people of an organisation is a property of the organisation, not of the people.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed to know.

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like it should be on `IOrganization` - that's what you'll call it on, after all. What you *have* is the organization, you *want* the list of people - you can't *start* fromt the list of people, so it *must* be part of the `IOrganization` interface.

I find it strange to have *plural* interface names to start with - I'd expect `IOrganization` for a single organization, and `IPerson` for a single person.

```
public interface IOrganization {
    IList<IPerson> GetPeople();
}
```

Comment: @hcb Then it'd probably be named IOrganizationList or IOrganizationCollection, rather than IOrganizations.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your should probably not have pluralized interface names. So call them IOrganization and IPerson and then on your `IOrganisation` interface you might have a method called:

```
IEnumerable<IPerson> GetPeople()
```

Answer (score 0):

Which belongs to which?

It seems to me that `iOrganisation.People` would be a list of people ( is your "IPeople" interface representing a list of people or a single person? ) belonging to the organisation. Likewise you might have an `IPeople.Organisations` that lists all organisations that a person belongs to. Both will probably have a different underlying mechanism - maybe calling the same lookup table - it doesn't matter to the person calling the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of an organization as a collection containing people, then it's intuitive to put that in `IOrganization`. It would look like this:

```
interface IOrganization
{
  IList<IPeople> Members { get; }
}
```